# ProxyDroid says it connects, but won't access the internet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, proxy

I'm trying to get my schools proxy to work through ProxyDroid on my Galaxy S3 4.1.1. I can use the proxy fine through the default settings application, but that only allows me to use my browser, no applications. With ProxyDroid I can't even get my proxy to work on the browser, much less any other app.

To use my dorm's WiFi (and ethernet) I am forced to log in through the proxy. I'm not sure what the problem could be. I've got the correct url (I also have a proxy.pac option, but it ProxyDroid woudln't read it) and correct authentication.

When I enable the proxy in ProxyDroid it says it connects fine, I just can't access the internet.

I am rooted.